# Translation for "of interest to"

Tags: translation, english-to-german

How would you say

> This video might be of interest to you.

in German?

I can think of

> Vielleicht interessiert Sie dieses Video.

which would be closer to `This video might interest you`.

I wonder if there's any nice phrase that corresponds to `of interest to`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can actually translate it directly:

> Dieses Video könnte für Sie von Interesse sein.

This phrase is a bit formal. You will find it most probably in business language. A similar phrase which is used more often:

> Ich habe nichts von Bedeutung gefunden.  - *I have found nothing of importance.*

Comment: And the less formal version would be "Dieses Video könnte dich interessieren."